# Stuggling to import from BarChart website

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm struggling to import data from the barchart.com website
I have tried importing the data presented on barchart.com/stocks/sectors/rankings?timeFrame=matrix without success.
I have tried using `IMPORTHTML` and `IMPORTXML` but neither works and I've tried various inputs.
If someone can please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this won't be possible. values which you want to scrape are controlled by JavaScript and Google Sheets does not support JS **scraping**. you can always test this by temporarily disabling JS on given URL to see what's possible to scrape:

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll then just have to find similar data somewhere else...